# Stability of nodal hypersurfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, singularity-theory, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

We denote by $\Pi_{n,d}$ the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in $n+1$ variables $x_0,\ldots,x_n$, i.e. $\Pi_{n,d}=\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C}),\mathcal{O}(d))$. The group $G=SL(n+1)$ acts on $\Pi_{n,d}$ by the change of variables. We recall that a point $f\in\Pi_{n,d}$ is called semistable if the closure of its orbit $\overline{Gf}$ does not contain zero. In general, the description of all semistable points in $\Pi_{n,d}$ is hard (see Chapter 4 in Mumford's GIT book), however it might be not so difficult to show that some point is semistable. For example, if $d\geq 2$ and the hypersurface
$$H_f=\{ x\in \mathbb{P}^n \; | \; f(x)=0\} $$
is smooth, then $f$ is a semistable point (see Proposition 4.2 in Mumford). I wish to have a similar statement for $f$ with (not worse than) nodal singularities as well.

Namely, we say that $f$ has nodal singularities if the Hessian matrix $\mathrm{Hess}_p(f)$ of $f$ has exactly one-dimensional kernel for each critical point $p\in \mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$ of the polynomial $f$ (since $f$ is homogeneous, the point $p$ itself is always in the kernel of $\mathrm{Hess}_p(f)$). In other words, the hypersurface $H_f$ has no singularities worse than simple node (however, $H_f$ could have more than one simple node). I wish to say that if $d\geq 3$ and $f$ has nodal singularities than $f$ is a semistable point in $\Pi_{n,d}$. Unfortunately, I can not locate this result in the literature except several cases. For instance, this is true if $(n,d)=(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(3,3)$ (Mumford, section 4.2) and is $(5,3)$ (Laza, The moduli space of cubic fourfolds), or $(4,3)$ (Allcock, The moduli space of cubic threefolds).

One could also try to apply the Hilbert-Mumford criterion to show that if $f$ is not a semistable point then $f$ has a singularity worse than a simple node. This works perfectly if $d>n+1$. Indeed, in that case the procedure described in section 4.2 in Mumford's book implies that if $f$ is not a semistable point, then the point $p=(0,\ldots,0,1) \in \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ is a critical point of $f$ and $\dim\ker \mathrm{Hess}_{p}(f) \geq 2$. If $d\leq n+1$, then the Hilbert-Mumford criterion does not seem to give an immediate answer; it is not even clear how to find a critical point of $f$ using it.